# Inner HTML of a table Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JavaScript and jQuery.. Here is my issue.

I have a table :
I want to find which `tr` has `td` with an `innerHTML` of either `Weekly`, `Daily` or `monthly`. Inside that `tr` i have to find and highlight `td`  that have `innerHTML` text `hello` with a particular color.

Here is the fiddle link of what i have tried so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/Adeyemi/gXGj6/8/

Comment: please elaborate on your attempts on solving the issue yourself, and read the [FAQ entry on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I have just updated the my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Adeyemi/gXGj6/8/.. hope that gives you a better understanding.. Thanks VERY MUCH

Comment: Ummm, your question is asking about a `td` with "hello", but your jsFiddle doesn't have any `td`s with "hello".

Comment: Please include the code within your posting.  Otherwise, when the fiddle links go bad, this is useless to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question and your fiddle - You want something like this.

[image]

Here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/gXGj6/12/

```
var myrow = $(".mtt");
$('td', myrow).each(function() {        
    if (this.innerHTML == 'Hello')
    {
        var title = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML;
        var colour = 'none';  
        switch(title) 
        {            
            case "Weekly":
                colour = 'green';
                break;
            case "Hourly":   
                colour = 'red';
                break;
            case "Daily":    
                colour = 'yellow';
                break;  
        }
        this.style.backgroundColor = colour;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Very much Mohammad Adil